# ubuntu /etc/apache2/conf-enabled uploadfiles

Tags: ubuntu

> /etc/apache2/conf-enabled

here i try to upload my script(sstmx) through winship but got error and i try these promotion also and ubuntu version 16.04

```
sudo chmod g+x /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/
    sudo chmod 775 /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/
```

[image]

i don't know how to upload that config any one can give some ideas its very helpful to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just upload it to your home folder in the server, then make "sudo su" and replace the file to the location "/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/"

Answer (score 0):

```
cd etc/apache2/conf-enabled
sudo nano sstmx.conf
```

try this